# How should I imagine $M_w[\epsilon]\downarrow$ for the empty halting problem or $M_w[w]\downarrow$

Tags: turing-machines, computability, halting-problem

I'm learning about computability problems e.g. reducing the general halting problem to the halting problem on a blank tape. But before I can understand this problem I first have to understand what exactly $M_w$, $M_w[\epsilon]$, and $M_w[w]$ are.

I know the concept of encoding a Turing machine $M$ e.g. by generating a string that describes the steps the machine can take. I assume this encoding represents the $w$ in $M_w$ and therefore $M_w$ means "Turing machine $M$ with encoding $w$".

Can I picture such a machine simply by its encoding-string $w$ written on a tape $T$?

Just to get a better understanding lets say `abc` encodes a TM $M$. So `abc` is written on a tape like this

$...\square$$\square$abc$\square$$\square...$

When I now think about the special halting problem with $M_w[w]\downarrow$ does it mean that $T$ looks like this:

$...\square$$\square$abcabc$\square$$\square...$

So first the encoding of the TM is written on $T$ and is followed by its input.

And is $M_w[\epsilon]$ simply
$...\square$$\square$abc$\square$$\square...$?

So on the tape is only the encoding $w$ of the machine?

I think a general understanding of how the machines are written/encoded on tape and what exactly something like $M_w[\epsilon]$ is, is absolutely fundamental in order to understand how something like $\mathcal{H}_w$ or  $\mathcal{H}_\epsilon$

I'd be thankful for detailed and intuitive answers that explain exactly the structure of stated machines/problems

Comment: I think its easier to imagine $\omega$ as a string that encods a machine ($\omega = "abc"$) and that $M_\omega$ *is* the Turing Machine that the string $\omega$ encodes. So $M_\omega[\omega]$ is just a TM (with encoding $\omega$) being run on its own code, so the tape is $... □□ abc □□ ... $. You seem to mix this up with $UTM[\omega, \omega]$, that is applying the Universal Turing Machine to use the code $\omega$ to simulate $M_\omega$ on the input $\omega$. In this case the tape is indeed $..□□abc \# abc □ □.. $

Comment: @plshelp ah I understand. So the way you describe it the machine whose function is encoded in $w$ is an entity operating on the band. Its encoding $w$ has nothing to do with the state of the Tape - it basically describes the operations that the head that operates on the tape will perform. So e.g. $M_w[x]$ with $w$ is describing the functionality of the machine itself and has nothing to do with the state of the tape whereas $x$ is the state/content of the tape... I hope I got this right.